# Delphi 10.1 Berlin Firemonkey TComboBox StyledSettings, Excluding the styles

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to exclude one TComboBox from styles. This one is a part of component and have another visual suit (manually painted with OnPaint event), but the main style of form has an influence on this TComboBox. Especially one parameter: FixedHeight - it causes that my TComboBox can't change the height...

How to do it? The TComboBox has no StyledSettings property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I found was to use another style... If there are some combobox-es with a fixed height, then I should create a copy of their style, but with fixed height equal zero.